# sql update in the same table based on quantities

Tags: sql

have the following table with 4 columns like this:

```
product quantity value id 
---------------------------
p1      -100       5   id1
p2        40       3   id1
p2        20       2   id1
p2        40       4   id1
```

I need a result where all the positive values get the value of the negative id.

output needed:

```
product quantity value id 
---------------------------
p1      -100       5   id1
p2        40       5   id1
p2        20       5   id1
p2        40       5   id1
```

there can be only one negative value for each id. All the items for each id must get the value of the negative one.

Comment: What do you have so far? Try to clear up your question a bit.

Comment: Can you display what you want your result output to be? Can you clear up your question - what do you mean by you need a 'general update'?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: i would like that all products with id1 to have the value = 5

Comment: general update = the table has a few hundreds lines with different id's

Comment: What if you have more than one row with a negative quantity but different `value` values.

Comment: for each id there is only one negative value , this is the rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it.

```
update the_table t1
   set value = (select value 
                from the_table t2
                where quantity < 0
                  and t2.id = t1.id)
where quantity > 0
  and id = 'id1';
```

The statement *will* fail if there is more than one row with quantity < -1 for the given id

Comment: actually it was something wrong with your code but i managed to do it like this based on yours:
update table
   set value = VAL
   FROM (  select product COD, value VAL
                from table
                where quantity < 0 AND id LIKE 'TT%' AND date BETWEEN '2014-06-01' AND '2014-06-30') TATALALICIES
where quantity > 0 AND id = COD